# Can't access JSON loaded with json.dumps(json.loads(input))

Tags: python, json, parsing

Suppose I have json data like this.

```
{"id": {"$oid": "57dbv34346"}, "from": {"$oid": "57dbv34346sbgwe"}, "type": "int"}
{"id": {"$oid": "57dbv34345"}, "from": {"$oid": "57dbv34345sbgwe"}, "type": "int"}
```

I wrote a script like this in python

```
import json
with open('klinks_buildson.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        distros_dict = json.dumps(json.loads(line), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        print distros_dict['from']
        print "\n"
```

But It is giving me an error:

```
print distros_dict['from']
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I want data of the from in both the lines.

Comment: Remove the `json.dumps()`. You should **only** be loading the value (and thus converting it to a Python datastructure), not dumping it (and turning it back from a Python datastructure to a string).

Comment: ...so, make the line with the assignment just `distros_dict = json.loads(line)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, give this as an answer?

Comment: @akshat, I'm not convinced this question *should* be answered, vs. closed-as-typo. Right now, I don't see how anyone else making the same mistake could find it without a much more specific title; thus, this is almost into close-as-typo territory, as an error unlikely to be replicated by anyone else (in a situation where the answer would actually be findable / help them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, sounds fair. :) I am still new here and also learning from other's experience. So, if you want to flag this, what point would you flag it under? I do not see any relevant option to flag it for closing.

Comment: @akshat, see the last option under the "off-topic" section. That said, if the title were edited to be specific to the failure mode, I could well revise my opinion.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, got it thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, everyone. It is working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load the line, you can load the file (assuming its valid json); like this:

```
with open('klinks_buildjson.json', 'r') as f:
   data = json.load(f)
```

Now `data` is a list, where each item is an object. You can iterate through it:

```
for row in data:
   print(row['from'])
```

To fix your immediate problem, remove `json.dumps` which is used to convert an object to a **s**tring, which is not what you want here.

```
distros_dict = json.loads(line)
```